# How we can prevent the row hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table with several row and each row contain a delete button.
Now if we click on delete button , corresponding row is deleted/hidden from the table.

I  want to implement alert "Do you want to delete ?"
if the answer is yes. Then only hidden the row ..
How we can achieve it..

```html
 <table>
 <tr class="alert alert-dismissable" >           
     <td>      
     Item 1                
     </td>
     <td>    
     <button  data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" >Delete</button>                 
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You should use javascript for that.

Answer (score 2):

By using javascript (add an attribute in the `HTML` -> `onclick="ConfirmDelete()"` and define it in the `JS`), one can do like the following:

**HTML:**

```
<button  data-dismiss="alert" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" >Delete</button>
```

**JS:**

```
function ConfirmDelete() {
var result = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");

if (result) {
  //User confirms to delete it
} else {
  //User doesn't confirms to delete it
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript for DOM manipulation.

[check the code here](https://jsbin.com/becenuteza/edit?html,output)

don't use data-dismiss api for hiding rows. It hides row instantly and don't bother about the conditions and logic in click event listener.

Comment: its not working.Because if we press  cancel button . the row deleted.

Comment: just edited..check it now.you are using bootstraps dismiss.i removed it

Answer (score 0):

By Jquery you can do this-

Your Html-

```
<table>
 <tr class="alert alert-dismissable" >               
 <td>        
 Item 1                
 </td>
 <td>      
 <button  data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-xs" type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete(this)">Delete</button>                 
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In JS

```
function ConfirmDelete(control) {
        var Confirm = confirm("Want to delete?"); 
        if (Confirm) {
          $(control).parent().parent().css("display","none")
        } else {
          //User doesn't confirms to delete it
        } 
    }
```

Comment: @EldhoseElias, According to your want, its hide the row, you can also hide row by visibility:hidden css. If you want to remove this row then simply use $(control).parent().parent().remove()

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code it may help you

```js
$(function(){
      $('table').on('click','tr a',function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var result = confirm("Are you sure to delete?");
         if (result) {
         $(this).parents('tr').remove();} else { alert('You Canceled');}

      });
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
<tr>
  <td class="active">Item 1</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="success">Item 2</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="info">Item 3</td>
  <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```